# Ignoring JSON fields when sending an object (deserialization)

Tags: java, json, spring

I have a DTO object

```
public class Rate {
    private final Integer rate;
    private final String user;
    private final Date date;
}
```

and two controllers

https://zapodaj.net/2f60536ba4326.png.html - GET the rating
https://zapodaj.net/71e52684343df.png.html - POST the rating

When adding the rating I do not want to add a user or date, because it is automatically completed on the sevice layer. How to ignore these fields so that they are not shown at all and that the user can not complete these fields when sending the assessment POST, and that they can only be seen when displaying GET.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the readOnly attribute to true for the properties which should be shown in the response, but not in the request.

```
private Integer rate;

@ApiModelProperty(readOnly = true)
private String user;

@ApiModelProperty(readOnly = true)
private Date date;
```

The model generated by swagger-fox will be

```
"definitions": {
    "Obj": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "date": {
                "type": "string",
                "format": "date-time",
                "readOnly": true
            },
            "rate": {
                "type": "integer",
                "format": "int32"
            },
            "user": {
                "type": "string",
                "readOnly": true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the swagger editor, it will be displayed in the following manner.

[image]

Comment: What do you think about the division of the Rate object into RateRequest and RateResponse?

Answer (score 0):

As the readOnly property got deprecated in newer versions of swagger-fox, i found the following to work instead :

```
@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
```

See reference : https://stackoverflow.com/a/69271572/17417290